# Servicestack session lost AFTER javascript API call-NOT A BUG

Tags: servicestack

I have my servicestack authentication and session accessible nicely in ASP.NET MVC, I can navigate between pages fine and retrieve the session with no issues and stay logged in on each page.

I can refresh pages, no issue.

However, as soon as I make an API call to a ServiceStack service, it causes a problem:

The service does NOT have [Authenticate] attribute on, and does not neccessarily require authentication, I can get the session during the first invocation of the service, however once the service returns and I navigate to another page or even refresh the same page I am no longer authenticated and the session is lost. Similarly if I call the service endpoint a second time the session data is no longer available.

https://github.com/darrenshrwd/InvestigateSSAuth

...**NOT A BUG**...I had left the following lines in, originally copied from my previous project:

```
    //Add a response filter (https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters) ...
    //...to CLEAR the user session after the service is executed as this is a Stateless service.
    GlobalResponseFilters.Add((req, res, dto) => req.RemoveSession());
```

Comment: Doesn't provide much to go on, many of [ServiceStack's Live Demos](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/LiveDemos) have authentication enabled and make Ajax API calls without any loss of Session. Will need a repro to explore further (GitHub?). What CacheClient are you using?

Comment: @mythz https://github.com/darrenshrwd/InvestigateSSAuth I've cut it down to just enough left to reproduce bug, Thanks.

Comment: ...of course it might not be a bug.

Comment: This project doesn't build on VS2012 or VS2015 preview due to incompatible NuGet version even tho I've got the latest version of NuGet installed. Tho I've looked at the src and don't understand why would you explicitly [Clear the Users Session after each request?](https://github.com/darrenshrwd/InvestigateSSAuth/blob/b5db855e46280ba3c2e8e7e0dfd07d121e98b6b1/EE/Code/ServiceStackAppHost.cs#L64) - which will have the effect of clearing the users session after each request.

Comment: Ah Sorry, left in from my previous project!!!  (I'm using VS2013)

Answer (score 1):

**NOT A BUG!!**

I stupidly had the following lines left in from my previous project:

```
    //Add a response filter (https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters) ...
    //...to CLEAR the user session after the service is executed as this is a Stateless service.
    GlobalResponseFilters.Add((req, res, dto) => req.RemoveSession());
```